# How to resolve the uninitialized constant user in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have Generated a new resources using activeadmin gem

```
rails g active_admin:resource user
```

After i restart my rails server its showing 
**/app/admin/user.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant User (NameError)**

I am using rails 4.0.3. and currently using active admin from git
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

Comment: Do you have a corresponding model in models/user.rb?  If you go to rails console can you do a User.new command without error?

Comment: @Jhon I figured out why it didn't work for me. Maybe it will help. In one of my models that "belongs_to" the User I had this: belongs_to :author, :class_name => "user", :foreign_key => :author_id, which works fine in my app but not with active admin. I had to remove that line and just use belongs_to :user. I am still trying to figure out how to get it working using a custom name though.

Answer (score 0):

Change `app/admin/user.rb` for `app/admin/users.rb`

Comment: by default active_admin needs the filename to be in plural to works.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. user used the generator, which creates a valid file and register by default.